# Flask TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql, flask, typeerror

I am building a dictionary app with Flask where users can add new words, the code below is the app.py file, I am having issues with the POST request, the error I am receiving on my terminal is this:

```py
line 45, in add_word
    word = request.get_json['word']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

*This code below is the app.py file*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import datetime
import pymysql.cursors
import json 

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'dictionary' 
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
mysql = MySQL(app, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

**@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])**
def index():
    user_response = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        *user_input = request.form['word']*
        conn = mysql.get_db()
        cur = conn.cursor() 
        cur.execute('select meaning from word where word=%s', (user_input) )
        rv = cur.fetchall()
        if (len(rv) > 0):
            user_response = rv[0]['meaning']
        else:
            user_response = 'The word can not be found in this dictionary, please try again with another word'
        
    return render_template('index.html', user_response = user_response)

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    conn = mysql.get_db()
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    cur.execute('select * from word')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()

return render_template('dashboard.html', words=rv)

**@app.route('/word', methods=['POST'])
def add_word():
    req = request.get_json() 
    word = request.get_json['word']
    meaning = request.get_json['meaning']
    conn = mysql.get_db()
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    cur.execute('insert into word(word, meaning) VALUES (%s, %s)', (word, meaning))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()

    return json.dumps('success')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*here is my dashboard page or route:*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title>Dictionary App - Dashboard</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block dash_active %}
class="active"
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <h2>Word Index</h2>
    <div class="col-md-2 sidenav">
        <a href="#" class="side-active" id="word-index">All Words</a>
        <a href="#" id="word-add">Add New</a>
        <div>
            <form action="javascript:0" id="word-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="word"> Word:</label>
                    <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    name="word" id="word" 
                    placeholder="Type in the word here: "
                    required> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label for="meaning"> Meaning: </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="meaning" placeholder="Type the meaning of the word shows here:" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="submit">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
              

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 main">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SN</th>
                <th>Word</th>
                <th>Meaning</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for word in words %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{loop.index}}</td>
                <td>{{word['word']}}</td>
                <td>{{word['meaning']}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">The Dictionary has no words at the moment</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You already have the line: `req = request.get_json()`. Now you just need lines like: `word = req['word']` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_json` is the actual method, which, as the error says, is not subscribable (i.e., doesn't support the `[]` syntax). You need to call it using parenthesis (`()`), and then subscript the return value.

You already saved the return value to `req`, now you just need to use it:

```py
req = request.get_json() 
word = req['word']
meaning = req['meaning']
```